# Foreach loop for change XML values (-1) and save to same file

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm trying to change a value in an XML file where I have a Price:

```xml
<Document-InventoryReport>
  <InventoryReport-Lines>
    <Line>
      <Line-Item>
        <id>1</id>
        <UnitNetPrice>13.9200</UnitNetPrice>
      </Line-Item>
      <Line-Item>
        <id>2</id>
        <UnitNetPrice>13.9200</UnitNetPrice>
      </Line-Item>
    </Line>
  </InventoryReport-Lines>
</Document-InventoryReport>
```

I want to replace the value of `<UnitNetPrice>` by the value minus 1.0.

I made some script but it's not saving this value using `foreach`:

```bsh
$xml = Get-Content -Path C:\Test\file.xml
foreach ($element in $xml.'Document-InventoryReport'.'InventoryReport-Lines'.'Line'.'Line-Item'.'UnitNetPrice') {
    $element - 1.0
}
```

Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: a `batch-file` tag not related to `batch-file`?

Comment: im open to do it also in bat if You have any idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several issues with your code:

1. You're not parsing the XML data, so you won't be able to access the values.

   Use either

   ```bsh
   [xml]$xml = Get-Content 'C:\Test\file.xml'
   ```

   or

   ```bsh
   $xml = New-Object Xml
   $xml.Load('C:\Test\file.xml')
   ```

   The latter is the recommended approach, but the former will work just as well in most situations.
2. Values from XML data structures are strings, so you need to cast them to a numeric type before you can do a subtraction.
3. Your code doesn't assign the modified value back to the XML node. Without that theXML data won't be updated, because PowerShell operators return the result to the caller. They don't update the first operand in-place.
4. When assigning the modified value back to the node you must convert the numeric value back to a string. Since the values are formatted as floating point numbers with 4 digits you probably want to use the [format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-3.0) (`-f`) for that:

   ```bsh
   '{0:f4}' -f 1.3
   ```
5. Using dot-access (`$xml.NODE.NODE...`) doesn't allow assigning the modified value back to the node, because that approach already expands the value of a leaf node, so `$element` contains the value rather than the node.

The recommended way of doing what you want to do is using `SelectNodes()` with an [XPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx) expression:

```bsh
$xml = New-Object Xml
$xml.Load('C:\Test\file.xml')

$expr = '//UnitNetPrice'
$xml.SelectNodes($expr) | ForEach-Object {
    $_.'#text' = '{0:f4}' -f ([double]$_.'#text' - 1.0)
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for all, but i still have a problem with ForEach loop, when i run $xml.SelectNodes($expr) i getting whole prices,but loop doesnt changeing anything any ideas where i should focus on?

Comment: @ŁukaszRykała I tested the code I posted with the data you posted, and it modified the XML data just fine. Of course you still need to save the modified data back to a file. That doesn't happen automagically.

Comment: Yea, but | Out-File ... replaceing for me an empty file what i cant understand why

Comment: @ŁukaszRykała Because `Out-File` is for writing *strings* to a file. You have an XML *object*. Use that object's `Save()` method.

Comment: Thanks! I added $xml.Save("C:\Test\data.xml") and this method works perfect!